# Javascript array includes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out if a array contains a specific index or not using the following codelines:

```
var array1 = [{ "abc": 123, "def": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1}]}]

console.log(array1.includes('def'));
```

---

The array contains "def" so the console should actually return true if I define the array in the following way:

```
var array1 = [{ "abc": 123, "def": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1}]}]
```

Defining it the other way, like:

```
var array1 = [{ "abc": 123 }]
```

should return false.

---

The code above therefore does not work correctly, does anyone have a idea whats causing it to respond a wrong boolean?

I appreciate any kind of suggestions!

Comment: The array doesn't contain `def`, it contains an object that contains `def`.

Comment: includes returns the boolean, but ur right about the object

Comment: *"The array contains `def`..."* – no, the array contains an *object* which has a `def` *property*

Answer (score 2):

The proper method would be `array1.some(n => n.hasOwnProperty('def'))`. See that there is no `def` in array, but rather object that contains `def` property

Comment: Quite possibly. It's really not clear what the question is asking, whether it may be nested further inside, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.includes` returns a boolean based on whether `(x)` is a *value* in the given `Array`, not keys. If you want `array1.includes('def')` to return the other parts then you must do `Object.keys(array1[0]).includes('def')`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do not indicate array you think of.

If you console.log 
`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array1)`, `array1` is an array of one object. To get proper result you have to check if the object inside have the `def` property, so:

```
array1[0].hasOwnProperty('def') // returns true
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is you try to access an element that is in an object and this object is in a list. To acces the list element, you need to specify its index (here 0). Then you can access the object keys with Object.keys.

```js
var array1 = [{ "abc": 123, "def": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1}]}]

Object.keys(array1[0]).forEach((element) => {
 if(element === "def") console.log(true);
})
```

Comment: Answers should be more than "You can do it like this.". They should explain the problem and the solution.